# manipulating the date and time from a datetime sql server type in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to create an auction site using asp.net. My auction's start date & time and end date & time are stored in my sql server 2008 r2 database as datetime types. I'm using vb.net. I'm trying to create a select statement in which I can query the date and time portion relative to the current date and time (so as to only display current ongoing auctions). I can successfully query the date portion using the Date.Now function, but the time is giving me a hassle. DateAndTime.Now doesn't work. I've even tried to separate the time and date in the database, but I still can't get an effective query.

Here are two examples of code which I've tried:

```
Dim Connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(...)
    Dim Command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    Dim _Reader As SqlDataReader
    Command.Connection = Connection
    Command.CommandText = "Select ... from Auctions where Start_Date_Time > " & DateAndTime.Now & " And End_Date_Time > " & DateAndTime.Now
```

Whereby Start_Date_Time and End_Date_Time are of type DateTime.

And:

```
Dim Connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(...)
    Dim Command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    Dim _Reader As SqlDataReader
    Command.Connection = Connection
    Command.CommandText = "Select ... from Auctions where Start_Date >= " & Date.Today & "Start_Time <= " & DateAndTime.Now.ToLongTimeString & " And End_Date >= " & Date.Today & " And End_Time <= " & DateAndTime.Now.ToLongTimeString
```

Whereby Start_Date and End_Date are of type Date, and Start_Time and End_Time are of type Time(7).

Any suggestions are appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use parameterised queries. Don't pass dates and times in as strings. Also you could consider using the TSQL `getdate()` and `dateadd` functions rather than passing parameters based on the current time in at all.

Comment: @Martin the only caveat about using T-SQL's values is that the server might be in a different time zone. We had an issue with this once where an app in the UK data center wrote to the database in Virginia and nobody could agree what the app should have been displaying or what should have been stored in the database. Since then I've always fought to deploy SQL and app servers in UTC, but if the app needs the app server's date/time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions guys. It was a simple error on my part. All I needed to do was put the DateAndTime.Now in inverted comma's.

So this code works :

```
Dim Connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(...)
Dim Command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
Dim _Reader As SqlDataReader
Command.Connection = Connection
Command.CommandText = "Select ... from Auctions where Start_Date_Time <= '" & DateAndTime.Now & "' And End_Date_Time >= '" & DateAndTime.Now & "'"
```

Comment: Do not use string concatenation. Not only will your performance suffer, but you open yourself up to SQL Injection attacks. Use Parameterized SQL instead.

Comment: @Jim Thanks for the advice, but this site will never go live. It's just for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
dim myDateTime as Datetime = Now()

...

Select ... from Auctions where Start_Date_Time > " & myDateTime.ToShortTimeString() & ...
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring.aspx

Comment: OP is using [DateAndTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c24ezyz.aspx), not DateTime.

Comment: @Tim -- actually, he's using that as well as just Time.  He could as easily use DateTime.  I don't think he really cares what the variable type is.  But I'll update my answer to clarify -- thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [DateAndTime.TimeString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime.timestring.aspx)?

`TimeString always returns the system time as "HH:mm:ss", which is a 24-hour format.` So depending on how the time portion of your DateTime is stored in your db, you may need to do some formatting.

```
Dim Connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(...) 
Dim Command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
Dim _Reader As SqlDataReader
Command.Connection = Connection          
Command.CommandText = "Select ... from Auctions where Start_Date >= " & Date.Today & "Start_Time <= " & DateAndTime.TimeString & " And End_Date >= " & Date.Today & " And End_Time <= " & DateAndTime.TimeString
```